# Webview not loading offline cached data

Tags: android, offline

I am having a problem with Webview in that it will not use the cache.
I start my app up, load the HTML5 page, then back out of the page, enter airplane mode on the phone, then try to go to the web page again. It should be cached, but I get a message saying that the URL could not be retrieved.

Here is my code pertaining to this. Am I doing something wrong???

```
String weblink = "http://abcd.com";
final ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "loading online..");
    mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    mWebview.loadUrl(weblink);
    setContentView(mWebview);
} 
else 
{
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "loading offline..");
    mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);

    mWebview.loadUrl(weblink);
    setContentView(mWebview);
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this issue? I have the exact same problem. Could you share the solution if you have one. Thanks Matt. Here's my duplicate problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549638/webview-not-displaying-website-when-offline

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok.

Either the Website does not exist or didn't get cached correctly, or your forgot to add the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Did you enable caching for your webview ? http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html

Comment: website is running correctly too and i see that in simulator's application setting 2.5 mb data is cached but not loading in webview ??
Please help me !!

Comment: yeah

    mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    mWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        
        mWebview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/com.tmi.app/cache");
        mWebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

Comment: Can you restart the whole process ? remove the app with its cache from the simulator, run it again online and then, switch to the airplane mode. For me, everything you've done is correct.

Comment: Ok let me try !!
Thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: It stops with message "the requested file was not found"

Comment: What if you replaced `WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY` with `WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK`

Comment: It says requested url not found

Comment: Thanks a lot Zakaria
but no hopes still :(

Comment: It could be worth using this ARO tool to understand what the phone is doing on the network side. This could help you to understand what is happening and what data is being fetched http://developer.att.com/developer/legalAgreementPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700312

Comment: Thanks Rod Burns ..
just checking it :)

Comment: I think no advantage to have a ARO for this :(

Comment: Are you using Android with another framework (ex: PhoneGap, Appcelerator, etc.) ?

Comment: @Zakaria : no just eclipse with latest android sdk

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Remove
```

> setContentView(mWebview);

```
in 
if and else both parts
```